# How to copy all contents under one kind of directory in ant?

Tags: ant

I'd like to copy files and subdirectories under directory `dir_java`, but not the `dir_java` directory itself and all its parent directories. a.k.a I'd like to get all directory `dir_com` and its subdirectories to `todir` in ant copy task.

Is there a way to do this?

```
temp
   \--dir_1
       |
       \--dir_java
           |
           \--dir_com
   \--dir_2
       |
       \--dir_java
           |
           \--dir_com
   \--dir_3
       |
       \--dir_foobar
```

There is no regularity for `dir_1`,`dir_2`,`dir_3`

I tried below

```
    <copy todir="to_dir" verbose="true" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="temp" includes="*/dir_java/**" />
    </copy>
```

But I got directories like `to_dir/dir_1/dir_java/dir_com`.

I want directories like `to_dir/dir_com`

My best trying was to add a exec task with invoking cp command after above copy task, but only for non windows platform:

```
    <exec executable="/bin/sh">
        <arg value="-c"/>
        <arg value="cp -R to_dir/*/dir_java/* to_dir"/>
    </exec>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all of the `dir_java` directories at the same level in the hierarchy? If so, consider using a [`<cutdirsmapper>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#cutdirs-mapper)...

> [cutdirsmapper] strips a configured number of leading directories from the source file name.

After `<cutdirsmapper>` removes the leading directories, it will preserve whatever remains of the directory structure...

```xml
<copy todir="to_dir" verbose="true" overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir="temp" includes="*/dir_java/**" />
    <cutdirsmapper dirs="2" />
</copy>
```

### Before running Ant

```
$ find . -type f
./temp/dir_1/dir_java/dir_com/1.txt
./temp/dir_2/dir_java/dir_com/2.txt
./temp/dir_3/dir_foobar/3.txt
```

### After running Ant

```
$ find . -type f
./temp/dir_1/dir_java/dir_com/1.txt
./temp/dir_2/dir_java/dir_com/2.txt
./temp/dir_3/dir_foobar/3.txt
./to_dir/dir_com/1.txt
./to_dir/dir_com/2.txt
```

Notice how `1.txt` and `2.txt` are still under `dir_com` after the mapping has been applied.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I wanted. I was doing this by invoking shell `cp -R` command to achieve. Yours are more elegent.